# upload large file from azure website to azure blob

Tags: php, azure, blob

I'm trying to upload a file of 32MB to the Azure blob. For that, I use uploadify, a PHP based script.

I've got another file of 21.9MB, that one works fine, but the larger file keeps giving me an IO-error. I've set my user.ini limit to the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 60M
post_max_size = 60M
memory_limit = 60M
max_input_time = 1200
max_execution_time = 1200
```

Am I forgetting a limit to set, or do I need to look at other things?

Comment: I'm not familiar with azure, but is there a limit on what can be uploaded as a single file? I think amazon limits it to 30 meg, which is why it came to mind.

Comment: I'm also worried it's that, something else, where does the M stand for in de upload_max_filesize, is that similar to MB? And the execution time is in seconds I guess?

Comment: Yes 'M' = Megabyte and time is in seconds.

Comment: Are you using Windows Azure PHP SDK to perform the uploading? Is this paged blob or block blob?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it rather than editing the answer into your question.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I wasn't able to answer my own question yet, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, what I did was the following:

Create a web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- other settings -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600" /> <!--100 MB-->
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
          <security>
            <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" /> <!--100 MB-->
            </requestFiltering>
          </security>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After this I only got an http 500 error, to solve this I added the following line to the .htaccess file:

```
LimitRequestBody 200MB
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things to understand with regard to your problem. If you use REST Api based (any programming language PHP, C#, Java, Python, NodeJs etc) solutions to upload/download blobs directly to & from Azure Storage, you will not hit such a small limit. In this case the blob size limit is set by Azure Blob Storage and the current limit is 1TB for each blob.

However when you use a webserver to upload/download files and there is underneath code within webserver to store uploaded file to Azure Blob Storage you will hit the limit provided by your web server. Your problem was related with Web Server settings.

I really wanted to clarify here is that what you have done above is modified the IIS web server settings to resolve your upload problem related with Uplodify script which is running in IIS web server. The file upload in any web server goes through HTTP and you have changed the IIS setting to accept a larger file over HTTP channel and changing web server configuration helped you here.